# Creating ASP.NET MVC Core app on Mac OSx with MS SQL Server db on Azure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, macos, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like to know whether anyone has successfully created ASP.NET MVC Core App with Azure hosted SQL Server as backend?
I'm trying to follow/mix up following tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs 
I created MVC app using yeo generator, it is running fine locally including Register link on landing page.
I deployed to Azure using local git, it runs upto displaying landing page, when I submit signup page I get error. Locally it's using SQLite .db file which I want to change to MS SQL Server db created on Azure. I put correct connection for this Azure SQL Server db in application settings and ran app from Azure link but got error.

Has anyone tried similar approach? I'm stuck here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some more Informationen about the errors you get and your apps configuration and dependencies.

Comment: @DevHew - I'm getting generic error, still trying to figure out how to enable full logging on Azure side, quite new in this setup. Will update original question later or by weekend. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are using EntityFramework Core. Wich packages do you installed?

Comment: I can't paste contents here due to characters limit, I've added source to Git, https://github.com/ssjsk/corewebapp2/blob/master/project.json , and https://github.com/ssjsk/corewebapp2/blob/master/global.json . I'm using EntityFramework Core. Thank you.

Comment: You need to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer in order to work with azure. You currently have only the sqlite package installed. Make sure to configure ef in Startup.cs.

Comment: Thank you DevHew, I managed to figure out after your reply :-)